# WCF streamed transport buffers 16K before sending anything

Tags: c#, wcf

**EDIT:** WCF seems to internally buffer 16K when using streamed transfer mode. Only after these 16K have been read from the stream does WCF send anything. Is there a way to configure this to a lower number? (For convrete example see code bellow).

I am wondering if it is possible to limit the number of bytes WCF reads from the returned stream before it starts sending. `maxBufferSize` property does not seem to limit this. Basically I have the following scenario:

App.config:

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfStreaming.Service">
    <endpoint address="/rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamedHttpBinding" contract="WcfStreaming.IService" behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehaviour"/>
  </service>
</services>


<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="streamedHttpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="256"/>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/data")]
    Stream GetData();
}
```

The service implementation:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Stream GetData()
    {
        return new DelayStream();
    }
}
```

And `DelayStream`:

```
public class DelayStream : Stream
{
    private int number = 0;

    public DelayStream()
    {
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int nc = 64;
        for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++)
        {
            byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(number++);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, buffer, offset + (i * sizeof(int)), sizeof(int));
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        return nc * sizeof(int);
    }

    // ... other Stream methods
}
```

**What happens:**

WCF starts by trying to read 256 bytes from the stream, then continues by reading 4096 bytes lots of times before it actually sends anything. If I run it with the `Thread.Sleep` (to simulate taking a long time to get data) it takes a long time before it actually starts sending anything.

It seems to be trying to read 16K before sending anything, but I set the buffer size to 256. Shouldn't this mean it should read 256 bytes and then send?

Or does anyone know how to force WCF to start sending data immediately?

Thanks, Iulian

Comment: How much does it buffer? Find out by making the data stream infinite. And maybe the config properties are in KB?!

Comment: It buffers 16,384 bytes. The `maxBufferSize` property is in bytes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.configuration.basichttprelaybindingelement.maxbuffersize.aspx

Comment: Hey lulian, did you fix your problem? I'm having the same issue, I need to stream 500 bytes per read and it seems to stream only 16k regardless of the maxBufferSize property.